# What ingredients make strengthen enchanting potions?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've recently been looking into enchanting on an epic scale, for example making things cost millions, doing tonnes more damge etc than what they would normally be able to do with just the enchanting perk tree filled out.

I was wondering, what ingredients besides Hagraven Claws and Snowberries are required to make strengthen enchanting potions?

Comment: I know enchanting something to be worth millions of dollars is possible, I've seen it done before on youtube, and in google images, I just haven't seen the materials used to make potions needed to do such things, other than the one I discovered via mixing hagraven claws and snowberries.

Comment: http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Alchemy_Effects

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are talking about, is the Fortify Restoration glitch.
You wear your highest % alchemy equipment and then get making!

Link to video here:

Ingredients are:

- Abecean Longfin
- Cyrodilic Spadetail
- Salt Pile
- Small Antlers
- Small Pearl
- Yellow Mountain Flower (Dawnguard Required)

Now heres what to do.

1) Make a restoration potion with any 2 ingredients shown above wearing your most powerful alchemy armor.

2) Drink the potion and take off your alchemy armor and put it back on without exiting the inventory menu.
Their % number should be slightly higher.

3) Repeat Step 1-2 until your armor and brewed potions show a ridiculous number.

4A) If making armor/weapons then make a Fortify Smithing potion. Wait until your at a forge and drink it.

4B) If enchanting, make a Fortify Enchantment potion and use it at an Arcane Enchanter.

4C) Recommended: You should make one more ridiculous Fortify Restoration potion to use later as you dont want to waste ingredients all over again to get a high %.

One way to get Abecean Longfin and Cyrodilic Spadetail quite easy are to go look for some near Riften and its rivers.

If you have Hearthfire DLC, at Winstad Manor, you can build a fishery.
Doing so will make a fishery at the water near your home down the hill.
Put some fish in there, and after a while you will get tons of them.

Hope this helped.

EDIT:

Making things with this will ridiculously increase their rating which increases their value probably costing more than a vendor can hold.

You will bankrupt everyone. ;)